# How to dodge duplication using EL?

Tags: java, jstl, el, duplicates

I'm rewriting my .*jsp* from scriplets to JSTL / EL and I'm facing an issue.  It's probably very simple but I'm new to EL and a bit lost.

Here's what I'm doing...

In the servlet/controller:

```
final List<Person> l = new ArrayList<Person>();
personList.add(...);
.
.
request.setAttribute( "personList", l );
```

And in my .*jsp*:

```
<c:forEach var="person" items="${personList}">
    ${person.name}
</c:forEach>
```

But I'm duplicating "personList" because I'm using it both in *setAttribute* and in the *forEach*.  How can I get rid of this duplication?

Ideally I'd like to have a constant, like a *public static final String*, that I could reference from both the servlet and the *.jsp* (using EL, not scriptlets).

Obviously the reason I want to eliminate this duplication is that if I decide to rename *personList* to, say, *persons* (with an 's'), I currently need to change two things and this is error-prone.  If I had a constant, there would only be one place where I'd need to make that change.

**EDIT** someone commented that using a constant, there would still need to be two places to change if I changed the name of the constant.  However there's a big difference for if I could do this:

request.setAttribute( Constants.PERSON_LIST, l );

then decide to rename *PERSON_LIST* and made a typo, that would break at compile time.

While if I mistype:

```
request.setAttribute( "persnList", l ); // forgetting an 'o' here
```

This will lamely compile and fail at runtime if the *.jsp* is using "personList" and not the mistyped "persnList".

Answer (score 1):

That's what you get when working with legacy/basic JSP/Servlets. You're manually doing all the front controller tasks yourself.

Move on to a real MVC framework. For example JSF, Spring MVC, Wicket, etc. Those frameworks have a single servlet (or filter) which acts as a front controller doing all the nasty preprocessing job of creating beans, putting them in the desired scope and so on. You end op working with just javabeans as models and JSP/Facelets files as views. In for example [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) all you need is then the following javabean (which will "automagically" be set in request scope by JSF itself):

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Persons {

    private List<Person> list;

    @EJB
    private PersonService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        list = service.list();
    }

    public List<Person> getList() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

And this Facelet view:

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{persons.list}" var="person">
    #{person.name}
</ui:repeat>
```

No duplication and when using decent IDE tools (e.g. Eclipse with JBoss Tools), then they are all linked to each other so that you can do *Source > Refactor > Rename* without pain.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really duplication is it? It is simply declaring a variable and accessing the variable in a single scope. That is perfectly fine. If you write a program and declare a variable on one line then later in the program you access the variable then you have the same problem...if you change the name of the variable as declared then all uses have to be found and changed.

In your example the scope is the request scope. So if you change a variable name in request scope then you have to go through the entire scope and change all references to the same variable. The fact that the declaration and the access occur in two different files should not be a big problem. That is not a problem that requires solving and the solution will probably result in convuluted hard to read code.

Comment: I disagree with your "answer".  It is definitely duplication and I explain why at the end of my question.  I have to change something in two places while, using scriptlets, it is totally trivial to not have this duplication.  It's not the same as a variable.

Comment: *"If you write a program and declare a variable on one line then later..."*...  A bit of a scretch to compare a variable on one line of a method with a "string" present, on one hand, in a servlet and, on the other hand, in a *.jsp* isn't it!?  Once again, using scriptlets it is trivial to not have this kind of duplication.

Comment: If you declare a constant how is it any different? You still have to fixup usages of it if you decide to rename the constant right?

Comment: @Kevin: if I could declare a constant then mistyping the name of the constant in either the servlet or the .jsp would break at compile time, not at runtime.  Here if I change "personList" to "persnList" in my servlet (typo by forgetting the 'o'), the webapp is going to compile fine but break at runtime.  A pretty big change isn't it?  By the way EL 3.0 made it easy to reference constants as far as I know (but I'm not yet on Jave EE 7).  I'm not seeing things here.

Comment: With JSP and Servlets you are simply working with a few more scopes than with a simple desktop type program. But it is the same thing. setAttribute() is simply creating a variable in request scope which you refer to later within the same scope. This is why we have automated testing. Where the compiler and the IDE fails your tests will pick up the problem and your broken code does not go into production.

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie: *"This is why we have automated testing. Where the compiler and the IDE fails your tests will pick up the problem and your broken code does not go into production"*... Oh please common, you're totally dodging the question and shifting the discussion here.  What I want to do is **TRIVIAL** to do using scriptlets and accessing constants from EL **CAN BE DONE** in EL 3.0 / Java EE 7.  So please now stop it.  Either you know how to prevent the duplication here, or you stop to try to shift the discussion and try to pretend there's no duplication here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but I think a standard problem with jsps is you don't see errors until the page loads. Even if constants fix this somehow what you describe is not duplication but a deficiency of EL variables in general (ie they're dynamically looked up at runtime)

Comment: but any IDE worth its grain of salt is going to warn you if you try to reference, say from a scriptlet, a constant that doesn't exist...  And starting from EL 3.0 you can reference constants :(  (sadly I'm not yet on Java EE 7)